# Flutter advance_pdf_viewer not working in release

Tags: flutter, pdf, release

I'm using the advance_pdf_viewer package to visualize a pdf file from a URL. It works fine in debug mode but when I build the release APK it doesn't work. That's how I use it:

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: PDFDocument.fromURL(widget.url),
        builder: (context, snap) {
          if (snap.hasData) {
            return PDFViewer(
              document: snap.data,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              showNavigation: true,
              showPicker: false,
              navigationBuilder:
                  (context, page, totalPages, jumpToPage, animateToPage) {
                return ButtonBar(
                  alignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.chevron_up),
                      onPressed: () {
                        animateToPage(page: page - 2);
                      },
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.chevron_down),
                      onPressed: () {
                        animateToPage(page: page);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          }
          if (snap.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text("Error"));
          }

          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
```

With 'it doesn't work' I mean that it always shows the text 'Error' in the center of the page.
I have already tried putting the internet permission in the Manifest.

The package version is the latest: `advance_pdf_viewer: ^1.2.2`

Also, I'm using Flutter flavors, if this can influence in some way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was just the URLs I used. The package requires a secure HTTP connection (https)
while my links were http